# Network section of Audio MIDI Setup freezes – how to fix?

Tags: macos, mac, networking, osx-snow-leopard, midi

I'm trying to setup a networked MIDI connection over WLAN from my iPad to my Mac, as [this guide](http://superprofundo.com/2011/01/05/use-your-ipad-as-a-wireless-midi-controller-for-ableton-live/) describes. However, when I open Audio MIDI Setup and go to Window -> Show MIDI Window, then click Network, nothing happens. If I click again the MIDI Network Setup window appears, but I can't interact with it. It also has no drop shadow as windows in Mac OS usually have (see picture).

I really have no idea of what's wrong, can anyone help me out?

[image: Print screen of MIDI Network Setup window]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a new configuration, switching to it, and then deleting the old one.